# Cannot get mcrypt for PHP5

Tags: apache2, php, aptitude

I've done this many times:

```
sudo aptitude install php5-mcrypt

sudo apache2ctl restart
```

aptitude says mcrypt is installed. I've reinstalled it 3 times already. I've restarted apache about 20 times since I installed it. When I look at phpInfo, I do not see mcrypt listed. When I try to execute my code it says the mcrypt function (pick one - any one) does not exist. mcrypt is clearly not enabled.

Does anyone have any idea what could be wrong? I do not know which pieces should be where and how all this is supposed to fit together.

I installed PHP 5.5.3

Comment: Did you install PHP from the package manager (`apt-get`/`aptitude`), too? The package `php5-mcrypt` can only configure the extension for `php.ini`s it "knows" about. Secondly, I don't now if `apache2ctl` reloads the modules. The "normal" way to restart Apache would be something like `sudo service apache2 restart`. Third, how is PHP connected to your Apache? If you use something like (f)cgi or php-fpm (in contrast to mod-php), you probably will to have restart PHP on its own, additionally to restarting Apache.

Comment: We installed everything using aptitude. apache2ctl stops and restarts apache. We've restarted the computer several times since these installs. Trust me when I say apache has been "restarted" since we installed php5-mcrypt - as well as PHP. PHP5 works fine as an apache module - it's a website written in PHP - so I assume PHP is installed as an apache module. If I go to /etc/apache2/mods-enabled php5 is in that list. I do not see mcrypt in /etc/php5/mods-available but if I do sudo aptitude search mcrypt I see 3 things installed: libmcypt4, mcrypt and php5-mcrypt - ????

Comment: Which `php.ini` is listed in the output of `phpinfo` (about 5th to 7th entry)? It should be a file in `/etc/php5/`. If you search in that file for `mcrypt`, what does come up?

Comment: php.ini is in /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini there is an mcrypt section in there with 2 settings - both commented out - mcrypt.algorithms_dir and mcrypt.modes_dir the comments above them say the default is /usr/local/lib/libmcrypt - those directories do not exist. This is what first clued me into the fact that mcrypt may not be installed although aptitude says it is. If I do sudo aptitude info mcrypt is says the package state  is installed - version 2.6.8-1.3 - it says Conflicts: mcrypt - so what is it saying? that this package conflicts with itself? Is there a better way to encrypt user info?

Comment: You don't need to care about the `mcrypt` package. That's the command line program that uses libmcrypt, as does the PHP extension. So you need to make sure the package `libmcrypt4` is installed. Is there a `php.ini` snippet at `/etc/php5/conf.d/mcrypt.ini`? That should load the lib. Is that snippet loaded by PHP (see `phpinfo`)? Again, have you tried to restart Apache with `sudo service apache2 restart` instead of `apache2ctl`?

Comment: there is a file: /etc/php5/conf.d/mcrypt.ini that contains extension=mcrypt.so - but I do not believe it's being loaded. There is no mcrypt section in phpinfo and the mcrypt functions do not exist (errors when I run my code) there is a /usr/lib/libmcrypt.so.4 link. what tells PHP to use mcrypt? is that it? do I need to tell PHP where to find it? I think I found the answer ... hang on ...

Comment: At the top of my phpInfo is a directory to scan for additional config files - it is /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d - it also lists additional config files that were loaded - that list did not include the mcrypt.ini file that is located at /etc/php5/conf.d - so mcrypt can be used in cli mode as well ??? I copied /etc/php5/conf.d/mcrypt.ini into /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d directory and restarted apache - mcrypt shows up in phpInfo and the functions are working. Thanks!!!

Comment: Most PHP extensions are installed for all "calling flavors" of PHP that are available on a machine, like apache2, cgi, cli etc. Glad I could set you on the right track, I posted an answer below :) The ini fragment should have been installed automatically, I don't know why it hasn't been.

Answer (score 62):

Try this

```
sudo php5enmod mcrypt

sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: Worked nicely and the symlink (over copying whole thing) is +1 for me. So upvoted!

Comment: This worked for me. But I did not need the first command (ln).
I had no mcrypt.ini within the /etc/php5/apache/conf.d folder. Running sudo php4enmod mcrypt worked. File there now. Server works!. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thanks its working fine. But I want know about the command that you used "sudo php5enmod mcrypt"..What is this ..? Whats the purpose of using this command..?

Comment: "sudo php5enmod mcrypt" will create a symlink in "/etc/php5/conf.d" directory with a priority number (default 20) so you can uninstall it without modifying ini files with "sudo php5dismod mcrypt"

Answer (score 11):

I had a similar problem on Ubuntu 13.10. Upon running composer install it produced the same error, ending in.

```
****Mcrypt PHP extension required.
Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the post-update-cmd event returned with an error

  [RuntimeException]  
  Error Output:****
```

I installed `mcrypt` and `php5-mcrypt` with aptitude, and still `php -m` did not show `mcrypt` as a loaded extension:

```
aptitude install mcrypt
aptitude install php5-mcrypt
```

I ran an `updatedb`, and then `locate mcrypt`. I found my `mcrypt.ini` in `/etc/php5/conf.d`. Yet all the other extensions (like json) had their .ini files in  `/etc/php5/apache2/conf.d` and `/etc/php5/cli/conf.d`. These both were links to `../../mods.available`.

So, I then moved `mcrypt.ini` to `/etc/php5/available-modules`, and set the links:

```
cd /etc/php5/cli/conf.d
ln -s ../../mods-available/mcrypt.ini 20-mcrypt.ini
```

And similarly for `/etc/php5/apache2/conf.d`.

And voila, it showed up in `php -m`!

Comment: Thanks so much for this answer. Totally sorted me out. Although I didn't move /etc/php5/conf.d/mcrypt.ini - I just set my symbolic links to point to that location which also worked and presumably will ensure future updates to mcrypt are automatically loaded?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the ini snippet that load libmcrypt when PHP is called by Apache is missing. There should be a file called `/etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/mcrypt.ini` with the following content

```
; configuration for php MCrypt module
extension=mcrypt.so
```

You should be able to copy it from the other PHP integration's vonfigurations like `/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/mcrypt.ini` or `/etc/php5/conf.d/mcrypt.ini`, depending on what's installed on your system.

Answer (score 2):

The mcrypt module is not enabled by default. Enable the mcrypt module and then restart apache ([credit](https://askubuntu.com/a/396338/12459))

```
sudo php5enmod mcrypt
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is it. Looks like sometimes we are in search of the most tangled way to do something as simple as 'enmod' ; )
Like Boinst says: 
`sudo php5enmod mcrypt`. 
Then reload apache.